# Coming back from home button pressed - activity finishes

Tags: android, android-activity, startactivityforresult

I have started an activity using startActivityForResult() and when I click the home button while on this new activity and then reopen the app the activity closes and it goes back to the previous activity. I have put the default implementations of the lifecycle methods in and set breakpoints and it goes through the following in sequence after opening the app again:

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // The activity has become visible (it is now "resumed").
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Another activity is taking focus (this activity is about to be "paused").
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // The activity is no longer visible (it is now "stopped")
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // The activity is about to be destroyed.
}
```

Why does it call onStop() and onDestroy()? I cannot have it do this. How do I stop it from doing this?

Comment: Which launchMode did You set in AndroidManifest?

Comment: The launchMode of the first activity is singleInstance and the launchMode of the second is unset.

Comment: I changed both to standard and it is at least not closing when I open it up now.